# Achieving numeric and special character internationalization in angularjs application

Tags: internationalization

How to implement internationalization in angularjs?
How to achieve multi language support including numeric(0 - 9) and all the special characters like - .,#$& etc. in angularjs application?

For *exapmle* - Suppose user has selected Chinese as the preferred language from application settings.
So I need to display him numeric data eg - $123,23.01 in Chinese.
Also here in **$123,23.01** after **$123** I have comma(,) but in Chinese the separator like comma(, and .) are different.

If anyone could share fiddle link of working copy or any clue, it will be a great help.

Thank you .. :)

Answer (score 0):

I could solve it using JavaScript's native method number.toLocalString.

```
    var number = 123456.789;

// request a currency format
console.log(number.toLocaleString('de-DE', { style: 'currency', currency: 'EUR' }));
// → 123.456,79
```

€

Comment: It may help someone in future, hence posting the answer.